# Vscode debugger not running for laravel on docker

Tags: php, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am running a laravel project in a docker container and I am using vs code to debug the project. 
I have a launch.json configured that works perfectly. 
if I run `docker exec -it main bash` the below below pathMappings is shown.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "main",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/home/virta/site/trunk": "/Users/masnadnehith/Desktop/bitbucket/main/"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            },
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have a new project laravel project that is a submodel that i cloned using git and added it inside the "main" directory calling it `main core` but the problem I am having is that now the `main core` is not able to run the debugger at all. 
So now I created the second configuration like this.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "main",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/home/virta/site/trunk": "/Users/masnadnehith/Desktop/bitbucket/main/"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            },
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "main-core",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "/Users/masnadnehith/Desktop/bitbucket/main/main-core"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            },
            "port": 9000
        },

    ]
}
```

The docker exec command is used to get the pathMapping for the new container.

Hence I am not sure why is the first configuration working perfectly for debugging the laravel project but the second configuration is not. 
The second one uses a different docker container (btw).
The first one was working without installing any sorts of extensions.

Php info already shows that the debugger is installed.

xdebug file below

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
; xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.idekey='VSCODE'
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping the port directly with the path, why not use `workspaceroot\main-core`

```
"pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/": "${workspaceRoot}/main-core"
            }
```